# Hola. Quiero acceder a las variables que creo en un evento cuando se pulsa un botón en java. Las variables solo existen en ese contexto:

Tags: java, arraylist, events

Este es el botón con el que creo las variables

```
 private void BttnGuardarDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        Doctores doc= new Doctores();//Este objeto lo quiero llamar en el siguiente botón
        int Did=Integer.parseInt(txtDid.getText());
        String dNombre=txtDnombre.getText();
        String dApellido=txtDapellido.getText();
        doc.id=Did;
        doc.nombre=dNombre;
        doc.apellido=dApellido;
    }
```

Este es el botón desde el que quiero acceder a las variables

```
private void BttnGuardarD3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    int pId=Integer.parseInt(txtPid.getText());
    String Pnombre=txtPnombre.getText();
    String Papellido=txtPapellido.getText();
    Paciente pacientes = new Paciente(pId,Pnombre,Papellido);
    doc.lPaciente.add(pacientes);//aquí se debe acceder al objeto creado arriba
}
```

Comment: Primero, pegaste el código del mismo botón las 2 veces. Segundo, si quieres acceder a las mismas variables en diferentes métodos tienes que declararlas globales, no locales como lo estás haciendo. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo corregí, voy a checar si puedo implementar lo que me comentas, gracias.

Comment: Debe declarar las variables que quiere que sean accesibles en metodos diferenes fuera del cuerpo de los métodos. Siempre que las declare dentro del cuerpo de los métodos son variables locales y estas solo tienen el ámbito del método en que se declaran